# Return only rows from a SQL table whose entry in a particular column is unique

Tags: sql, postgresql

How does one return only rows from a SQL table whose entry in a particular column is unique?

For example,

Let's say I have the table:

```
FRUIT   COLOR
_____________

apple   green    
apple   red    
peach   blue
banana  red
```

I would like to write a PostgreSQL query which returns only those rows whose entry in the `FRUIT` column is unique, which in this case means returning the last 2 rows.  How do I do that?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is an elementary exercise on using the `having` clause. Read the documentation: [Aggregate Functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tutorial-agg.html) and compare these queries:

```
select fruit, count(*)
from my_table
group by 1;

 fruit  | count 
--------+-------
 banana |     1
 peach  |     1
 apple  |     2
(3 rows)


select fruit
from my_table
group by 1
having count(*) = 1;

 fruit  
--------
 banana
 peach
(2 rows)
```

Comment: what if OP wanted the whole rows ?

Comment: He could use an aggregate, e.g. `max(color)` in select.

Comment: `luck` is undefined in Postgres.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to get whole row,

1) Use `having` and `join`:

```
select t.*
from
  my_table as t join (
    select fruit
    from my_table
    group by fruit
    having count(*) = 1) as f on (t.fruit = f.fruit);
```

2) Use window function:

```
select *
from (
  select *, count(*) over (partition by fruit) as cnt
  from my_table) as t
where
  cnt = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Typical SQL Syntax for specific column is that

```
 SELECT * FROM (
   SELECT FRUIT, Count(FRUIT) AS NUM_OF_FRUITS FROM MyTable
   GROUP BY City )
 WHERE NUM_OF_FRUITS = 1
```

gives the peach and banana but if you want to take whole row you can use below sql syntax as

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable 
WHERE FRUIT IN  (
    SELECT * FROM (
        SELECT FRUIT, Count(FRUIT) AS NUM_OF_FRUITS FROM MyTable
        GROUP BY City )
    WHERE NUM_OF_FRUITS = 1 
)
```

I assume it is sufficient for your question.

Comment: can't we have `COUNT(FRUIT)` in where clause without the subquery ?

Comment: @Abelisto but that would need a `GROUP BY` which in effect necessitates the subquery to return what we want(unless OP could accept `GROUP BY`'s output)